# Python beginner - find an object in a list through input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here. I've created a class with some hockeyteam-objects, witch I put in a list. I now want to let the user type in a name of one of the teams and make the program find it in the object-list(later I want to add results to the teams but this is not my issue for the moment)

This is the code I've wrote so far.

```
class team:
    def __init__(self, name, wins, losses):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({} {} {})'.format(self.name, self.wins, self.losses)    

detroit_red_wings = team("Detroit".ljust(10), 2, 1)
los_angeles_kings = team("Los Angeles".ljust(10), 2, 0)
toronto_maple_leafs = team("Toronto".ljust(10), 0, 1)

teamlist = [detroit_red_wings, los_angeles_kings, toronto_maple_leafs]
print(teamlist)

def input_results():
    home_team = input("Type in the home team: ")
    for i in teamlist:
        if i.name == home_team:
            print("the team was found!")
        else:
            print("the team was not found! ")

input_results()
```

The result I get is that the program writes "the team was not found" three times!

Comment: did you input the name of one of the teams in the list? It's hard to help you if we dont know what your input is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing string comparison on your input and team name, the two need to be an exact match to get 'the team was found'. For whatever reason, you're adding a bunch of padding to the team names, so your Detroit team name is actually `"Detroit   "`. This is very likely the problem.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You are looking for your team name, but when you created your
   `team`objects you added spaces to the teamname (the `.ljust(10)`
   part). So you have to strip those again when looking for a match
   (the `rstrip()` part in the code below)
2. You are printing "the team was not found!" every time if no match is found. It is better to `return` the result.

Updated version of your code:

```
def input_results():
    home_team = input("Type in the home team: ")
    if home_team.rstrip() in teamlist:
        return "the team was found!"
    else:
        return "the team was not found! "

result = input_results()
print(result)
```

Comment: That´s right, the  ".ljust(10)" - part was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I would make the conditions easier by ignoring capitalization (by converting to upper case before comparison) and leading/trailing whitespace (by using the `strip()` method). Probably you don't get a result because of the `ljust(10)` you used that adds spaces to the right side of the string until it's at least 10 characters long.

Also instead of a for loop you can use an `in` check:

```
def input_results():
    home_team = input("Type in the home team: ")
    if home_team.strip().upper() in (team.strip().upper() for team in teamlist):
        print("the team was found!")
    else:
        print("the team was not found! ")
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea to convert the strings to upper case letters before comparing them!